# CSS <td> vertical spacing - can't make it go away

Tags: css, html-table, space

Trying to get rid of the vertical space between the 'td' tags on the following page:

http://framework.matthewruddy.com/2008/09/04/layout-test/3/

How can I make it go away? I cannot figure it out. It isn't happening in IE at all, oddly.

Tried the following CSS, along with a reset CSS.

`table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two things here:**

In your `body` tag, you have set the `line-height` to `24px`. You should override this for all table elements, or, in fact, just set it on `p` tags.

Also you have set the `td` `.post-content .more` to have a `margin: 15px 0` so that is causing your rows to have an additional 15px top and bottom.

Comment: That got it! Thanks a million. Didn't see that class.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.label` class is adding top+bottom padding/margins

---

This is an x-browser inconsistency use Eric Mayer's CSS Reset:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Add this to your StyleSheet:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've already used Eric's reset CSS (also added one or two of my own properties): http://pastebin.com/55yCGQTP

Comment: @MatthewRuddy Yeah, I'm just going through your page in CSSEdit now :)